# Tabulating data in R with 3 variables?

Tags: r, tabular

I'm trying to create a table to understand some of this data.

```
bsa_2010 <-read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ubl9huokroj9jw8/bsa%202010.csv")
> dput(head(bsa_2010))
structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("England", 
"Scotland", "Wales"), class = "factor"), RSex = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    RAge = c(75L, 34L, 81L, 25L, 33L, 76L), MarStat = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Living as married", "Married", 
    "Not married", "Separated or divorced after marrying", "Widowed"
    ), class = "factor"), ChildHh = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), WhPaper = structure(c(8L, 
    8L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 8L), .Label = c("(Scottish) Daily Express", 
    "(Scottish) Daily Mail", "Daily Mirror/ Scottish Mirror", 
    "Daily Record", "Daily Star", "Daily Telegraph", "Financial Times", 
    "Skip,not read paper normally", "The Guardian", "The Independent", 
    "The Sun/ Scottish Sun", "The Times"), class = "factor"), 
    PartyIDN = structure(c(2L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("British National Party (BNP)/ National Front", 
    "Conservative", "Don't know", "Green Party", "Labour", "Liberal Democrat", 
    "None", "Other answer (WRITE IN)", "Other party (WRITE IN)", 
    "Plaid Cymru", "Refused to say", "Scottish National Party", 
    "UK Independence Party (UKIP)/Veritas"), class = "factor"), 
    Partyid1 = structure(c(2L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("British National Party (BNP)/ National Front", 
    "Conservative", "Don't know", "Green Party", "Labour", "Liberal Democrat", 
    "None", "Other answer", "Other party", "Plaid Cymru", "Refusal", 
    "Scottish National Party", "UK Independence Party (UKIP)/Veritas"
    ), class = "factor"), PartyId2 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Conservative", "Green Party", "Labour", 
    "Liberal Democrat", "None", "Other party", "Other/DK/Ref"
    ), class = "factor"), Spend1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L), .Label = c("(None of these)", "Defence", "Education", 
    "Health", "Help for industry", "Housing", "Overseas aid", 
    "Police and prisons", "Public transport", "Roads", "Social security benefits"
    ), class = "factor"), Spend2 = structure(c(6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    9L, 10L), .Label = c("(None of these)", "Defence", "Education", 
    "Health", "Help for industry", "Housing", "Overseas aid", 
    "Police and prisons", "Public transport", "Roads", "Skip,no 1st priority", 
    "Social security benefits"), class = "factor"), RClassGp = structure(c(4L, 
    6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("Employers in small org; own account workers", 
    "Intermediate occupations", "Lower supervisory & technical occupations", 
    "Managerial & professional occups", "Not classifiable", "Semi-routine & routine occupations", 
    "Skip, never had a job+DK+NA last job"), class = "factor"), 
    RNSSECG = structure(c(4L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 8L), .Label = c("1.1", 
    "1.2", "Intermediate occupations", "Lower managerial and professional occupations", 
    "Lower supervisory & technical occupations", "Not classified", 
    "Routine occupations", "Semi-routine Occupations", "Small employers and own account workers"
    ), class = "factor"), CanLegal = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Taking cannabis should remain illegal", 
    "should be legal, only licenced shops"), class = "factor"), 
    RaceOri3 = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("ASIAN: of Bangladeshi origin", 
    "ASIAN: of Chinese origin", "ASIAN: of Indian origin", "ASIAN: of Pakistani origin", 
    "ASIAN: of other origin (WRITE IN)", "BLACK: of African origin", 
    "BLACK: of Caribbean origin", "MIXED ORIGIN (WRITE IN)", 
    "OTHER (WRITE IN)", "WHITE: of any origin"), class = "factor"), 
    Agecat1 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("(18,28]", 
    "(28,38]", "(38,48]", "(48,58]", "(58,68]", "(68,78]", "(78,88]", 
    "(88,98]"), class = "factor"), Agecat2 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("(18,38]", "(38,58]", "(58,78]", 
    "(78,98]"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Country", "RSex", 
"RAge", "MarStat", "ChildHh", "WhPaper", "PartyIDN", "Partyid1", 
"PartyId2", "Spend1", "Spend2", "RClassGp", "RNSSECG", "CanLegal", 
"RaceOri3", "Agecat1", "Agecat2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Basically I'm trying to study the relationship between age, political standing and views on cannabis legalisation.

Variables used are: RAge (Age) PartyIDN (Political party identified) CanLegal (Cannabis Legalisation)

To simplify it, I've put ages into categories and kept only two of the biggest political parties.

```
   bsa_2010$Agecat1 <- cut(bsa_2010$RAge, c(18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88,98))

    Parties <- subset(bsa_2010, PartyIDN == "Conservative" | PartyIDN == "Labour")

   Parties$PartyIDN <- factor(Parties$PartyIDN)
```

How would I produce a table that shows the relationship between RAge, PartyIDN and CanLegal to get a clear understanding of the 3?

Answer (score 0):

`table()` is a barebones tabulation function, but still very useful:

Try

```
table(Parties[c("Agecat1", "PartyIDN", "CanLegal")])
```

You'll get:

```
, , CanLegal = should be legal, only licenced shops

         PartyIDN
Agecat1   Conservative Labour
  (18,28]            7      6
  (28,38]           12     17
  (38,48]           19     18
  (48,58]            7     11
  (58,68]           16     14
  (68,78]            9      4
  (78,88]            2      1
  (88,98]            0      1

, , CanLegal = Taking cannabis should remain illegal

         PartyIDN
Agecat1   Conservative Labour
  (18,28]           14     21
  (28,38]           25     29
  (38,48]           27     39
  (48,58]           23     17
  (58,68]           45     43
  (68,78]           36     28
  (78,88]           16     18
  (88,98]            4      2
```

UPDATE:

To add labels to the categories, use `cut`'s `labels` argument.
Since you mention you would like to further simplify the age categories (just three labels, "millennials", "working age", "retirees") your code
Your code would look like this:

```
bsa_2010$Agecat1 <- cut(bsa_2010$RAge, 
                        breaks = c(18,35,65, max(bsa_2010$RAge)), 
                        labels = c("millennials", "working age", "retirees"))

Parties <- subset(bsa_2010, PartyIDN == "Conservative" | PartyIDN == "Labour")

Parties$PartyIDN <- factor(Parties$PartyIDN)


tabulation <- table(Parties[c("CanLegal", "Agecat1", "PartyIDN")])

tabulation
```

Results will look like this:

```
, , PartyIDN = Conservative

                                       Agecat1
CanLegal                                millennials working age retirees
  should be legal, only licenced shops           18          37       17
  Taking cannabis should remain illegal          27          90       73

, , PartyIDN = Labour

                                       Agecat1
CanLegal                                millennials working age retirees
  should be legal, only licenced shops           21          42        9
  Taking cannabis should remain illegal          38         101       58
```

You can also easily plot the table using `mosaicplot`:

```
mosaicplot(tabulation)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think this would work better if I removed the categories from age, and just left it as a continuous variable?

Comment: No, using a continuous category will make things less clear.

On the opposite, I would simplify the age variable even more, reducing it to maybe three categories, say 18:35 (millenials), 35:65 (working adults), 65+ (retirees)  -or whatever your understanding is of a good generational split

Comment: @KaoruTakedaManimaran ;  or you could plot the data - keep age continuous, and plot its distribution for each category interaction.

Comment: How would I add labels for the split from age variables to produce millennials/working ages/retirees?

Eg I'd like to produce a clear table that shows how millennials/working ages/retirees interact with the CanLegal variable

Comment: @KaoruTakedaManimaran please check my updated answer, and don't forget to accept it if it addresses your question :)